# How to output XML safe string in PHP?

Tags: php, xml

I am doing some stuff that needs to output xml(utf-8) using PHP scripts. It has strict format requirements, which means the xml must be well formed. I know 'htmlspecialchars' to escape, but I don't know how to ensure that. Is there some functions/libraries to ensure everything is well formed?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [PHP DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) or [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).  These will also handle escaping for you.

Answer (score 0):

The Matthew answer indicates the "framework" for produce your XML code.

If you need only simple functions to work with your XML class or do "XML-translations", here is a didactic example (replace `xmlsafe` function by `htmlspecialchars` function).

PS: remember that **safe  UTF-8 XML not need a full entity encode**, you need only [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)... Not require all special characters to be translated to entities.

Only 3 or 4 characters need to be escaped in a string of XML content: `>`, `<`, `&`, and optional `"`. See also the XML specification,  http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/ "2.4 Character Data and Markup" and "4.6 Predefined Entities".

The following PHP function will make a XML completely safe:

```
// it is for illustration, use htmlspecialchars($s,flag).
function xmlsafe($s,$intoQuotes=0) {
if ($intoQuotes)
    return str_replace(array('&','>','<','"'), array('&amp;','&gt;','&lt;','&quot;'), $s);
    // SAME AS htmlspecialchars($s)
else
    return str_replace(array('&','>','<'), array('&amp;','&gt;','&lt;'), $s);
    // SAME AS htmlspecialchars($s,ENT_NOQUOTES)
}

// example of SAFE XML CONSTRUCTION
function xmlTag( $element, $attribs, $contents = NULL) {
$out = '<' . $element;
foreach( $attribs as $name => $val )
   $out .= ' '.$name.'="'. xmlsafe( $val,1 ) .'"';  // convert quotes
if ( $contents==='' || is_null($contents) )
    $out .= '/>';
else
    $out .= '>'.xmlsafe( $contents )."</$element>";  // not convert quotes
return $out;
}
```

In a CDATA block you not need use this function... But, please, avoid the indiscriminate use of CDATA.